# How can I sart at the same time more than one (many) cucumber test(s)?

Tags: google-chrome, testing, cucumber, watir-webdriver

I want to sart at the same time more than one cucumber test with the help of watir-webdriver. How can I get(start) it? Is it possible?

Comment: Your question is wrong. Sounds like you want to test contention handling which is one test. Spend more words describing the test problem you are trying to solve, not the problem with your implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [parallel_tests](https://github.com/grosser/parallel_tests) gem. I have some example code at [watir-parallel](https://github.com/zeljkofilipin/watir-parallel).

By default parallel_tests gem uses the number of available CPUs to determine how many processes to run in parallel:

```
-n [PROCESSES] How many processes to use, default: available CPUs
```

If for some reason for you the number is 1, you can explicitly set that option to another number, for example:

```
parallel_cucumber features/ -n 2
```

Comment: It's good, but not that, what I need. I want to start for example 2 tests. I want to see 2 browser-windows at the same time on my screen (on my two screens (monitors)). And this cucumber tests must run in two browsers (windows) at the same time. Is it possible?

Comment: So, the problem is that you want each browser on separate monitor?

Comment: No, I want to see running 2 or more tests at the same time. In 2 or more browsers.

Comment: I why do you think parallel_tests gem does not solve that problem?

Comment: Because it start it one after another.

Comment: I see. You want them started exactly *at the same time*. I think that is impossible. How much delay would you tolerate? 1 s? 1 ms?

Comment: I do not think you can do _anything_ at the _exactly_ same time.

Comment: 1-5 seconds is ok. But not one after another.

Comment: I do not understand. "1-5 seconds is ok." and "But not one after another." are contradictory, as far as I understand it. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I mean, the second test start after end of first and not after 1-5 seconds, when first began to run.

Comment: Must I have more than 1 processor?

Comment: No. I think by default `-n` option is set to the number of cores or processors that the machine has, but you can set the option to any number.